# Automatically trigger shift button after space in TextField - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, textfield

I want the user to be typing into a text field but it always capitalises the start of each word. I have tried the `.capitalise` modifier on the string but it removes any capitals in the middle of the name, so isn't what I want.

My aim is to have the keyboard automatically press SHIFT when there is a space, the user can then choose to 'un shift' or use the capitals. Is there a modifier for the textField I don't know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [autocapitalization()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/autocapitalization(_:)):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var string: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            TextField("Enter here...", text: $string)
                .autocapitalization(.words) // <~ HERE
            Text("You wrote: \(string)")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]